# How to allow anonymous users to submit webform in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7

I created the webform , gave it permission " to be submitted by anonymous users " yet only the title of the form & the submit button is visible and not the fields of webform to the anonymous users . 
I am using drupal 7 , how to solve this problem ?

Drupalgardens support had it resolved for their client and most probably it is a bug . 
Link : http://www.drupalgardens.com/content/anonymous-users-cant-complete-webforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that during creation of fields , I made the fields invisible for other users which made it invisible in resultant form  .

Now it's working just fine .